# How to omit keys with empty (non-zero) values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a dict `{ 'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': {} }` and I need to omit all keys that have empty values (0 is not considered to be empty). So, the output of this should be `{ 'a': 'a', 'b': 0 }`.

For `{ 'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': { 'd': 'd' } }` --> `{ 'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': { 'd': 'd' } }`;

I tried something like `{k: v for k,v in my_dict.items() if not v}`, but I'm not sure how to preserve 0s;

I'm looking for something like https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omitBy

Comment: Just change your condition to `v == 0 or not v` to include zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function that takes a predicate for filtering based on values:

```
def omit_by(dct, predicate=lambda x: x!=0 and not x):
    return {k: v for k, v in dct.items() if not predicate(v)}

dct = { 'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': {} }
print(omit_by(dct))
# {'a': 'a', 'b': 0}

dct =  {'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': { 'd': 'd' } }
print(omit_by(dct))
# {'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': {'d': 'd'}}
```

Simply change the predicate to what suites you.

Comment: This does the opposite of lodash's `omitBy()`: It includes all items which match the predicate, whereas the name suggests the opposite.  I don't see much point in defining such a function in the first place, since just spelling out the dictionary comprehension is both more readable and faster.  I also don't understand the output of the last example; it looks like there is a redefinition of `dct` missing.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Done some cleanup. Had a copy and paste issue with the last part; fixed. Used a function to match the use of a predicate as with Lodash. They are free to remove it. Thanks for the eye.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
res = { k:v for k,v in source_dict.items() if (hasattr(v, '__len__') and len(v) > 0) or isinstance(v, int) }
```

**Note:** You must adapt the `if ...` part of the comprehension to suit your needs. The condition here works for the types you show in the example but you'll have to add condition as needed (also, given the different types you have in the key, the condition can grow quite a bit...)

Comment: What about `None`?

Comment: This is will yield an error for `0` for ints don't have length

Comment: @Denis you'll have t adapt the condition to match what your data ctually is (see my edit for None)

Comment: @TheophileDano, true, but his question is extremely generic on the definition of 'empty'. He needs to adapt the 'if ...' part of the comprehension to whatever he needs

Answer (score 0):

```
def purify(dict):
    for k,v in dict:
        if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, set) or isinstance(v, dict):
            if len(v) == 0:
                del dict[k]
    return dict
```

You can use it like so: `dict = purify(src)`

Comment: Not only those types have a `len()`. A more general condition would be IMO `if v is not None and `hasattr(v, '__len__')`

Comment: No need to check for `None`-ness here

Comment: Yeah that was a copy-paste leftover from a test I made to check what None returns with `hasattr`

Comment: Moreover, `hasattr([], "len")` returns `False`.

Comment: That's because the attribute name is `__len__` and not `len`

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a function to test whether an item is empty? ( the definition of 'empty' can be quite custom in ur usage for me)

```
def not_empty(item):
    '''
    define what's empty
    '''
    if isinstance(item, (dict, list)) and (not item):
       return False
    if item is None:
       return False
    # add more situations?
    return True

    sample_dict = { 'a': 'a', 'b': 0, 'c': {} }

    result = {k:v for k,v  in sample_dict.items() if not_empty(v)}
```